# Forecasting a year ahead using annual vs daily data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prediction-interval

Suppose, as an example, that you would like to forecast a share price in a year's time based on the past 20 years of data. You can either use annual data and forecast 1 period ahead, or use daily data and forecast 365 days ahead. Clearly, there are far fewer data points in the annual dataset than in the daily dataset.

I am finding that there is much greater uncertainty/variability in the forecast based on the daily data than in the forecast based on the annual data (wider prediction intervals for the former). I was wondering if this is to be expected in general or if it is problem/model specific.

Comment: What do you mean by "annual data"? Do you mean data averaged over a year? Or are you using daily data but only choosing  to use the closing price for the "same day" each year?

Comment: The closing price for the same day each year (so not averaged).

Comment: Although I happen to be working with financial data, my question is intended to be more conceptual: if your goal is to predict a year ahead, how would you expect the frequency of the observed data to influence the confidence in your prediction?